Proving cross product and dot product is smooth 2-form on $S^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$
I'm studying for comprehensive exams, and one question is the following:

Show that $\omega : S^2 \rightarrow \Lambda^2 T^* S^2$ defined by $w_p(U,V) = p \cdot (U \times V)$ is a smooth 2-form.

Here, the $\cdot$ refers to the usual dot product and $\times$ refers to the usual cross product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I can answer this if I use what I know about calculus by manually calculating cross products and dot products and turning it into a differential form by invoking the one-to-one correspondence between vector fields and differential forms, which is ok but feels a bit like cheating. I'm not sure how one would rigorously prove this, just using the language of smooth manifolds. What would be the appropriate way to approach this problem?
Thanks in advance for any responses!

Think of this $2$-form as first being defined on $\Bbb R^3$. There smoothness should be clear — it’s a polynomial in three vector variables. (Or just write it directly as a determinant.) Then the pullback (restriction) to $S^2$ is automatically smooth because the inclusion map is smooth. –
